# applet does not run in browser

Tags: java, applet

I am very new to Java, just completed a Java fundamentals coarse. already found a lot of answers and help on the diffenrent forums on the web.
I have designed an Applet with sql db access. Running it on NetBeans IDE 7.2.1, it works 100%, but as soon as i run it with a `.html` file with the `NetBeans` view command, I get the following error.

```
äccess denied "java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInpackage.sun.jdbc.odbc"
```

I have already added the following lines to the java policy file in the jre directory.

```
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.sun.jdbc.odbc", "read";
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.sun.jdbc.odbc", "write";
permission java.util.PropertyPermission "file.encoding", "read";
permission java.util.PropertyPermission "file.encoding", "write";
```

what am i doing wrong, or what is required to run the applet in the browser?

Comment: New to Stack Overflow as well!! Please post the properly indented stack trace henceforth..

Comment: Why do you want to access database by applet? Is it local database to a client?

Comment: Please mention your problem statement. The current approach you are taking is definitely not the best design to interact with database when you need data in browser.

Comment: @Santosh When trying to run the Applet on the browser, i don't get any stack error in Netbeans, only the error mentioned above which i display with showStatus() on the Applet.

Comment: @Nikolay Kuznetsov. It is a logging system, so the Applet will be accessed by all the customers/clients and the database will sit on my server. How do i get info from applet to my database then?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that applets can open JDBC connections from sandbox. You probably have to sign your applet something like this

http://www.qoppa.com/faq/signapplet.htm

Comment: You think wrong.  A sand-boxed applet can 'phone home' to a DB.  Whether they *should* open a direct connection to the DB is another matter (they should not).

Comment: @AndrewThompson you might want to take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336335/how-to-connect-to-sql-database-from-applet

Comment: The problem on that thread is not phoning home to the applet, but as clearly stated `AccessControlException: access denied       (java.util.PropertyPermission file.encoding read`.  It is a different thing.

Comment: @AndrewThompson look at exception trace äccess denied "java.lang.RuntimePermission" it clearly says its a permission issue

Comment: Did you even ***read*** my comment?  If not, go back and read it again as many times as required, to understand it.  If you do not understand it even then, ask questions rather than post *more* words that underline your inexperience.

Comment: Let me try running it locally. If it allows to make DB connections by default, I will term it as a bad decision.

Comment: *"Let me try running it locally"*  Make sure you test it in a browser, rather than an IDE.  An IDE typically won't add a `SecurityManager`.